# Ethernet and wifi are gone

Tags: wireless, networking

Just rebooted an HP SpectreXT netbook after a Kubuntu update and there's no more network access. ifconfig only shows 'lo'. In the network manager I cannot turn on wifi. The ethernet cable is connected and blinking. I tried `dmesg | grep -i "net\|eth\|wifi\|wireless\|wlan"` but there's very little of interest:
NET registered protocol family 16/2/1/10/17
4 lines about NetLabel
And two apparmor lines about NetworkManager being unconfined

I checked the BIOS and there's nothing about networks.
What else can I try ? Thanks

Comment: Problem miraculously went away...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I booted using the previous kernel and everything worked fine. So I did aptitude full-upgrade again and everything worked fine. I guess the previous upgrade had failed somehow.